# JUnit spring can't inject related beans that located in other project using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

i'm working in spring project and i want to create a unit test using JUnit but i get null pointer exception , this is my code :

i create the test in my project (A) :

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:**/applicationContext.xml"})
public class EditionArticleTest {

 @Autowired
 private ArticleService articleService ;

@Test
    public void testfindArticleByNum()
        throws Exception
    {

    //this line return null pointer Exception
     Article article =  articleService.findArticle("AA0045");
   }

}
```

the problem is that the implementation of my service depend on a bean that  is located in an other project (B) , like this :

```
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements articleService {

//the implementation of this bean exists in an other project
 private ArticleFinder articleFinder ;

}
```

so i get the error in this line :

```
 @Override
    public Article findArticle( String numArticle )
    {
       //iget the null pointer exception in this line because spring can't 
       //instantiate the beans articleFinder 
        return articleFinder.findByNumArticle( numArticle );
    }
```

please do you have any suggestion to solve this problem and force spring to inject all related beans that located in an other project automatically.

Regards.

Comment: Does the other project have a way to import its beans? like `@Configuration` class or something? I think it's happening because spring doesn't scan the other project's beans. Can you post your `applicationContext.xml` file?

Comment: Hi @GuySmorodinsky thank you for your time, yes exactly each project has its applicationContext.xml so my Project (A) can't scan the applicationContext.xml in the project (B) so this is why it cn't find the bean

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options.
1. You can mock those dependencies which you don't need and Inject into depending class using `@InjectMocks` and mock the behaviour od the methods of those class which are called
2. You can include all the beans which you need in applicationContext.xml or include only the classes which are needed using
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {abc.class, def.class})`

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran , thank you for your time, i prefer the Option 2 , please do you have any idea on how to scan applicationContext.xml of the Project(A) and applicationContext.xml of the Project (B) in the same time using  @ContextConfiguration?